# Cannot extract parts of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this : `SPList:6E5F5E0D-0CA4-426C-A523-134BA33369D7?SPWeb:C5DD2ADA-E0C4-4971-961F-233789297FE9:`.

Using Javascript, I would like to extract the two IDs (which can be different) : `6E5F5E0D-0CA4-426C-A523-134BA33369D7` and `C5DD2ADA-E0C4-4971-961F-233789297FE9`.

I'm using this regular expression : `^SPList\:(?:[0-9A-Za-z\-]+)\?SPWeb\:(?:[0-9A-Za-z\-]+)\:$`.

I expect this expression to extract into two matching groups the two IDs.

By now, my code is :

```
var input = "SPList:6E5F5E0D-0CA4-426C-A523-134BA33369D7?SPWeb:C5DD2ADA-E0C4-4971-961F-233789297FE9:";

var myregex = /^SPList\:(?:[0-9A-Za-z\-]+)\?SPWeb\:(?:[0-9A-Za-z\-]+)\:$/g;

var match = input.match(myregex);

var listId = match[0];
var webId = match[1];
```

However, this is not working as expected. The first match contains the whole string, and the second match is undefined.

What is the proper way to extract my ID's?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cRSVc/) that illustrate my issue.

Comment: You're using non-capturing groups (`(?:...)`). Are you sure this really is what you need?

Comment: @sp00m: not at all. I may have misunderstood something. If I'm wrong let me know :). I'm used to write regex for .Net. I'm new to javascript ones

Comment: Will input always be "valid"? If so you can simply look for `SPList` and `SPWeb` and accept the rest of the string.

Comment: @Passerby: I don't get you. The input is always valid (checked before)

Comment: @SteveB if `input` is always valid, which means it will always be `SPList:<listId>?SPWeb:<webId>:`, you can simply match `/^SPList\:(.+?)\?SPWeb\:(.+?)\:$/` or even, use `input.indexOf("SPList:")`,`input.indexOf("?SPWeb:")`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should suit your needs:

```
var regex = /^SPList:([0-9A-F-]+)[?]SPWeb:([0-9A-F-]+):$/g;
var match = regex.exec(input);
var listId = match[1];
var webId = match[2];
```

I simply replaced the non-capturing groups of your initial regex by capturing groups, and used `regex.exec(input)` instead of `input.match(regex)` to get the captured data. Also, since the IDs seem to be hexadecimal values, I used `A-F` instead of `A-Z`.

Comment: This works as expected. I'll have to read a bit about this capuring and non-capturing groups, as it's puzzling me :). Anyways, thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
        var myregex = /[^\:]([0-9A-Z\-]+)[^\?|\:]/g;
        var match = input.match(myregex);
        alert("listID: " + match[1] + "\n" + "webID: " + match[3]);
```